# Cannot remove <file>: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, files, rm

I just ran some self-written program in which I make files and fill them with stuff. However, I did something wrong (or at least, not as intended) with the name generation and now there are four files stuck in the folder which cannot be removed as they 'do not exist'.

Outputs of commands:

`ls -li`:

```
ls: cannot access Ã©Ã©n: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access wetenschapÂ­pen.: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access verantwoorÂ­delijk: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access woordÂ wordt: No such file or directory
total 0
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Ã©Ã©n
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? woordÂ wordt
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? verantwoorÂ­delijk
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? wetenschapÂ­pen.
```

`rm -i -- *`:

```
rm: remove regular file `Ã©Ã©n'? y
rm: cannot remove `Ã©Ã©n': No such file or directory
rm: remove regular file `woordÂ wordt'? y
rm: cannot remove `woordÂ wordt': No such file or directory
rm: remove regular file `verantwoorÂ­delijk'? y
rm: cannot remove `verantwoorÂ­delijk': No such file or directory
rm: remove regular file `wetenschapÂ­pen.'? y
rm: cannot remove `wetenschapÂ­pen.': No such file or directory
```

`rm -rf folder`: (with 'folder' being the folder the files reside in)

```
rm: cannot remove `folder': Directory not empty
```

`find . -type f -delete`: (as from the answer of Uditha Desilva)

```
find: cannot delete `./Ã©Ã©n': No such file or directory
find: cannot delete `./wetenschapÂ­pen.': No such file or directory
find: cannot delete `./verantwoorÂ­delijk': No such file or directory
find: cannot delete `./woordÂ wordt': No such file or directory
```

`strace -o out rm -f -- *`: [Contents of out](http://pastebin.com/XtYXKnCb)

How can I remove these files?
Important to note is that I do not have root access, so I would prefer an option which does not require that.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS with Linux 3.13.0-79

Comment: What filesystem?  Can you unmount it and `fsck` it?  The output from `strace -o /some/output/file rm -f -- *` or `strace -o /output/file find . -type f -delete` run from in the directory would also be interesting.

Comment: The filesystem is ext4. As stated I have no root access, so no unmounting and fsck'ing. Output of strace is in question.

Comment: Well, that's really strange.  Can you post the output from `strace` running the `find . -type f -delete` command?

Comment: Is it an option to remove the complete directory?

Comment: If your program can reproduce these errors, it may be useful to system devs in a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the file from UI as Move to trash.
and then go to trash and delete from there. This process will permanently delete your file from your linux system.

Comment: Someone care to explain why this worked while the rest did not? (did not test tachomi's answer though)

Answer (score 0):

It's almost as if you've managed to write garbage into the directory inode itself rather than into files within it. However, try

```
find . -type f -delete
```

which doesn't try to do shell expansions of the files and may thus succeed.

EDIT: The answer by tachomi does appear to be the most likely explanation, but it isn't possible to "cd" into a directory with 400 mode, or list its' contents once you are in it, so that does not fit perfectly either:

```
$ chmod 400 test
$ ls -li test
ls: cannot access test/Pictures: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/Music: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/Shows: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/TV: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/Movies: Permission denied
total 0
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Movies
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Music
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Pictures
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Shows
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? TV
$ cd test
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
$ chmod 700 test
$ cd test
$ ls -li
total 0
267447 -rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 0 Mar  3 19:45 Movies
267448 -rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 0 Mar  3 19:45 Music
267449 -rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 0 Mar  3 19:45 Pictures
267451 -rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 0 Mar  3 19:45 Shows
267450 -rw-r--r-- 1 abcd abcd 0 Mar  3 19:45 TV
```

However, the delete may have worked if the GUI delete process changed directory permissions "behind the scenes" prior to removal.

Comment: Didn't work, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the missing execute permission in the directory, the user can't do a `stat()` but can read the dir entries.

To avoid this you can do `chmod 700` to the main directory.

To reproduce again this behavior you can do a `chmod 600` or `chmod 400` on any dir and it will have the same issue.

```
$ chmod 400 folder
$ ls - ltr folder
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? omd
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file5
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file3.txt
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file2.txt

$ chmod 700 folder
$ ls - ltr folder
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tachomi tachomi  2 Mar  2 08:53 file4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tachomi tachomi  2 Mar  2 08:53 file5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tachomi tachomi  0 Mar  2 08:53 omd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tachomi tachomi  2 Mar  2 09:01 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tachomi tachomi  2 Mar  2 09:01 file2.txt
```

Give a try